# как вставлять изображения в подписи электронной почты без вложения в Outlook c #?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

У меня есть два письма из Outlook

[с моего приложения add-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvOK3.png)

[з New Email в Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuXxB.png)

Мой код:

```
var attachment = oMailItem.Attachments.Add(match.Value, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Signature");
            attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то картинка кодируется в base64 и вставляется в само письмо с помощью html кода. Попробуйте сделать тоже самое, а не прикреплять ее.